# Cell is losing gradientLayer after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, gradient

In my UITableview I create a gradient layer and apply it to individual cells.

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
CGRect gradframe = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
gradient.frame = gradframe;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:.9 green:.9 blue:.9 alpha:1.0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:.8 green:.8 blue:.8 alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];

[cell setBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
[cell.backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0] ;
```

When I scroll offscreen and scroll back through my cells they lose their gradient layer.

I am still a bit new to ios development and any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: This will only happen sometimes. When scrolling up and down very occasionally there will be a cell that has the layer. And even these cells are not consistent.

Comment: I guess your problem is somewhere else within cellForRowAtindexPath. Show a bit more code for that.

Comment: Hi,Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `cell.bounds` instead of `cell.frame`, since the gradient frame should be relative to the cell.  `NSLog` the gradient frame as shown below, and verify that the origin is {0,0}.

```
NSLog( @"%@", NSStringFromCGRect( gradient.frame ) );
```

Also, be careful, each time you pull a cell out of the reuse queue, it will still be configured as when it went into the reuse queue.  So you need to make sure that you don't add a gradient to a cell that already has a gradient, or you could run into memory problems.

---

I think this is what you wanted for `gradframe`

```
CGRect gradframe = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Yes! using cell.frame allowed the gradient to stay. The reason I used gradframe above is to extend the colored texture, because the cell.bounds.size.width stop short on the ipad leaving a white space for the rest of the cell. any way to fix this?

Comment: @user3009729 ok, I didn't fully understand what you were doing with `gradframe`.  I've added a suggestion to my answer.